# How to check whether the payload is null within choice component in mule?

Tags: database, mule, payload, isnullorempty

I am retrieving some data using stored procedure and calling it within the database connector in mule. I have to include a condition when I pass a value which is not there in the database it should capture the error. For this I am using a choice component where I have to check whether the payload is null. But when running the flow in debug mode I found that the `payload` holds the value 
`{resultSet1=[]}`. I tried `#[message.payload.isEmpty()]`, `#[message.payload!=null]` and `#[payload.resultSet1 != null]`. But they weren't working. Could anyone help to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `empty` to check for:

> Testing for Emptiness: The special literal empty tests the emptiness of a value. It returns an empty value depending on context. empty evaluates to:
>
> - null
> - boolean false
> - empty strings or strings containing only white space
> - zero
> - empty collections
>
> The expression #[foo == empty] evaluates to true if the value if foo satisfies any of the requirements for emptiness.

Which in your case would be

```
#[payload.resultSet1 != empty]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is #[payload != null && payload.size()>0]

Answer (score -1):

you can try comparing with 'null" or "0" or, simply, "empty" and it should work fine for you :)

Answer (score -2):

```
 #[payload == empty]
```

should work.